# Binding a comboBox to a DataTable with dependency property

Tags: wpf, combobox, datatable, wpf-controls, dependency-properties

I have retrieved a code implementing a `ComboBox` with `Image` and `Text`. I have managed to make it work but have no idea why. I would be so grateful if a charitable soul could explain me, what's going on there! Here is the code, in the `XAML` I have:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DiagramDesigner.App_UserControls.RichComboBox.RichComboBox" Name="ucRichCombo"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:Convert="clr-namespace:DiagramDesigner.App_UserControls.RichComboBox.ComboImageConverter" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Height="Auto" Width="Auto">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <Convert:ComboImageConverter x:Key="Converters" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ComboBox Name="cbRichCombo"  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ucRichCombo, Path=ComboDataTable}" SelectedValuePath="country_code_iso_2"  SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=ucRichCombo, Path=country_code_iso_2}" >
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="spComboItem" MinWidth="150">
                    <Image Name="iComboItem" Width="20" Height="20" Margin="1,0,3,0" Source="{Binding Path=country_code_iso_2, ConverterParameter='COMBOFLAGS', Converter={StaticResource Converters}}"/>
                    <TextBlock Name="tComboItem" Margin="2,0,2,0" Text="{Binding country_name}" Width="Auto" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

`ComboDataTable` is a `DataTable` associated with the `comboBox` in the code behing as follow:

```
public partial class RichComboBox : UserControl
{
    public RichComboBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public DataTable ComboDataTable
    {
        get { return (DataTable)GetValue(ComboDataTableProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ComboDataTableProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ComboDataTableProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ComboDataTable", typeof(DataTable), typeof(RichComboBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

}
```

My questions are the following:

- I don't understand what is the dependency property doing. Obviously it is needed I guess passing information to the children Image and textBlock controls but I have no idea how. I understand the datacontext is already passed through the ItemSource binding.
- My second question is about the datatable. The column names are used like properties, by what #@?! mechanism? It seems wpf is doing hidden things even behind the code behind. Nobody is talking about this and it seems quite weird and frustrating to me.
- How can I modify this code to pass as variables the column names in the datatable I want to use respectively as selection field and display. Currently, they are hard coded in the Xaml (country_code_iso_2 and country_name).

Many thanks in advance.